# Entry config error

Tags: python, widget, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a program that needs to change the state of the widget but the problem is I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Programming\Spellox\Spellox.py", line 67, in <module>
      new_word()
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Programming\Spellox\Spellox.py", line 37, in new_word
     entry['state'] = DISABLED
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

Can anyone help here is my code for the entry widget:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()

entry = Entry(root, fg='blue', textvariable=check_var).pack(side=TOP)

def change():
     time.sleep(3)
     entry['state'] = DISABLED

change()

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pack` returns nothing. So entry now is a `None`. Besides, using `time.sleep` in `tk` is not a good choice. You may use:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
check_var = StringVar()
entry = Entry(root, fg='blue', textvariable=check_var)

def change():
     entry['state'] = DISABLED

entry.after(3000, change)
entry.pack(side=TOP)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the `pack` method of `Entry` actually returns `None`, not the entrybox.  You can see this by putting `print(entry)` right beneath the line where you define `entry`.  It will print `None` in the terminal.  To fix this problem, put `pack` on it's own line like this:

```
entry = Entry(root, fg='blue', textvariable=check_var)
entry.pack(side=TOP)
```

Now, `entry` refers to the entrybox like it should, not the `pack` method of the entrybox.

Also, if you plan to use `change` repeatedly in your script, then putting it in a named function is a good thing.  Otherwise, I would simply do this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

check_var = StringVar()
entry = Entry(root, fg='blue', textvariable=check_var)
entry.pack(side=TOP)

entry.after(3000, lambda:entry.config(state=DISABLED))

root.mainloop()
```

It's more concise and using a `lambda` means there is no need to define a whole named function just to be used one time.

Comment: While what you say is true and the code works, you didn't address what the real problem was (hint: it has nothing to do with the use of lambda)

Comment: @BryanOakley: Thanks for the tip.  Let me add a 101.